# Does anyone know the name of this purple flower?

Tags: identification

I got this flower from a small bouquet and dried it, but I don't know the  name and google hasn't been usefull yet. Does someone recognize it? Thanks in advance.

[image]

I have another picture of the plant, dried opside down, so it's not flat. I can definetly say that the leaves were not needlelike, in fact, there weren't barely any on it. It has a deep purple colour, almost wine red, but a bit more purple. If I look at the pictures of the different kinds of heath or heather, it seems that they are a collection of stems, and each has many flowers on it, but here you can see that there is one stem, that itself has many branches with many flowers. Would it stil be some sort of heath/heather?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I agree it is most likely some kind of heath or heather, of which there are three types; Erica, Calluna and Daboecia. There are one or two very large ones which reach up to six feet or more, but the average height is between 6 inches to 2 feet. This is clearly a spray from one of the larger varieties, and I can say it's probably not Daboecia because the flowers seem too small. Whether its an Erica or Calluna is hard to say because the stem is now dried, but you may be able to tell with very close examination (or from memory when it was freshly cut) whether the leaves were needlelike or were like overlapping scales - if the latter, it's Calluna of some variety, the former will ID it as an Erica variety. https://www.saga.co.uk/magazine/home-garden/gardening/advice-tips/winter-garden/growing-winter-flowering-heathers

Answer (score 0):

It looks more like dried "lucky heather" than lavender to me.

If it is lavender, that should be obvious from the smell. Heather doesn't smell much - it may smell slightly acrid and "woody".

Pictures here: http://daisyshop.co.uk/Mini-dried-lucky-heather-flowers-2-weeks

Comment: Looks a bit big for heather, also remaining leaf at the bottom is not at all like heather. Also not particularly like lavender...

Comment: My first guess was some sort of (dried?) fern - not a flower at all. But that's just a guess. Unless the OP doesn't know what lavender smells like, it would be hard *not* to recognize it if it was lavender, IMO.